# Import OrientDB into MangoDB Database

Tags: mongodb, migration, orientdb

I am trying to export data from Orient DB, which is backup.gz, and import it into the MongoDB Atlas database.

Is there any tool or help to complete this task?

I use the the OrientDB database export module to get theckup.gzkup.gz file, which is in in JSON format.
I am using the the MongoDB Import tool to import that.gzfile,, and it is not possible.

I am looking for an online tool or migration tool through which I can achieve this. I also o  tried Studio 3T.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about the behavior or error that you're observing? mongoimport [accepts JSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/#json-format), so are you saying the compressed format of the file is causing a problem? If so, can you uncompress it first?

Answer (score -1):

instead you can migrate to arcadedb and use that in mongodb-mode

Comment: What I understand is, I can migrate Orientdb to Arcadedb and then Arcadedb to Mongodb. 

If the assumption is correct, please share some links or tool names to do that.

Comment: AcadeDB understands mongodb-queries. Thus you got a proxy of a mongodb which is compatible to orientdb. ArcadeDB claims that you even might use an usual mongodb-adapter.